# Text break with special characters python

Tags: python, xml, string

Hello comunity i have a trouble writing a XML file with python.

Text i want write in a FILE:

```
<!-- @(#) $Id: ./etc/rules/apache_rules.xml, 2011/09/08 dcid Exp $

  -  Official Apache rules for OSSEC.
  -
  -  Copyright (C) 2009 Trend Micro Inc.
  -  All rights reserved.
  -
  -  This program is a free software; you can redistribute it
  -  and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public
  -  License (version 2) as published by the FSF - Free Software
  -  Foundation.
-->

 <rule id="30100" level="0">
    <decoded_as>apache-errorlog</decoded_as>
    <description>Apache messages grouped.</description>
  </rule>
```

But the simbol ; in comment, break the string and on my file only got

```
<!-- @(#) $Id: ./etc/rules/apache_rules.xml, 2011/09/08 dcid Exp $

  -  Official Apache rules for OSSEC.
  -
  -  Copyright (C) 2009 Trend Micro Inc.
  -  All rights reserved.
  -
  -  This program is a free software
```

Without ; write all, i can replace that simbol but another can crash text again ?? and why ??

PS: im writig file with

```
f = open("/tmp/l.xml",'w')
f.write(data["contentXML"])
```

Comment: Maybe *write* works correctly but your `data["contentXML"]` does not contain everything you thought. Did you check that? How are you filling it with data?

Comment: Yeah i print content off data and all content is there.